# Polygon.io getting splits and dividends for multiple tickers

Tags: python-3.x, stockquotes, polygon.io

I notice in Polygon.io it's possible to get quotes on a list of tickers.  I see how to get splits and dividends on a single ticker.  Is there a way to get splits and dividends on multiple tickers with one api call?  How would I adjust this code to do that:

```
y = requests.get('https://api.polygon.io/v3/reference/splits? Ticker=IBM&apiKey=secretkey').json()
print(y)

z= requests.get('https://api.polygon.io/v3/reference/dividends? Ticker=IBM&apiKey=secretkey').json()
print(z)
```